# Latitude Longitude Plot in X, Y

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

Why do we use longitude and latitude as `(x, y)` when plotting? Latitude (equator) lines run horizontally and longitude (prime median) lines run vertically across the earth. So why it is not `(x, y) == (latitude, longitude)`?

Comment: Taimur I am curious if you are asking why the convention uses latitude for horizontal and longitude for vertical instead of the opposite or why we use `x` for the longitude/vertical lines and `y` for the latitude/horizontal lines

Comment: actually, why we use x for the longitude/vertical lines and y for the latitude/horizontal lines was my question

Comment: Does my answer clarify that at all?

Comment: i was expecting more clarification. Now got the answer. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of [Google Earth](http://earth.google.com/web/@36.94626702,-108.78481016,1815.75809908a,1582416.30827487d,35y,-0h,0t,0r),

[image]

The vertical lines of course are longitudinal and the horizontal lines are latitudinal. An appropriate corresponding plot in matplotlib would look like this

[image]

where longitude changes along the `x` axis and latitude changes along the `y` axis. Therefore, `(x, y) == (longitude, latitude)`

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, because it uses the premise that the OP questions. I mean at the end it boils down to the quesiton why we have north on top in maps and that is a mainly a cultural agreement, right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest OP does seem to be asking why we use `x` for longitudes *given* longitudes run vertically but I’ll admit that’s my speculation. It certainly is ultimately just convention which is latitude and which longitude

Comment: Yep, could be better suited for a GIS forum or so. Concerning programming, maybe the equivalent would be why do we use (theta, r) in a polar plot, instead of (r, theta).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest or why we use theta for inclination and phi for azimuth (or rather why azimuth and inclination are not reversed)